# Solidity - Mapping a List

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I have a Map of a List.  I am managing the data in the map and the list.   I have it working for now, but wanted to find out if there is a better way to do this.

```
mapping (bytes32 => Receipts[]) receiptsByPersonMap;
Receipts[] dummyReceiptsList;

Receipts newReceipt = new Receipts(_person, _cost);

dummyReceiptsList = receiptsByPersonMap[_person];

dummyReceiptsList.push(newReceipt);
receiptsByPersonMap[_person] = dummyReceiptsList;
```

This works for now.  it seems that the last line is irrelevant - if  receiptsList is pointing to the same storage space.  Any suggestion of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in one go? Something like:

`receiptsByPersonMap[_person].push(new Receipts(_person, _cost));`

Incidentally, this may just be an artifact of the way you've simplified the question to post here, but since `_person` is the key of the mapping where you store your `Receipts` record, you can't access it unless you already know `_person`, so you should be able to remove `_person` from the struct. At that point the struct only contains one item, so you could get rid of it entirely and just store `cost` in a `bytes32 => uint256[]` mapping.

Comment: Thanks @EdmundEdgar.   Your suggestion is perfect..   Yes, I had simplified the struct for this question.